# бат файл не работает

Tags: cmd, bat

```sh
For %%_ in ("C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Search\Data\Applications\Windows\Windows.edb") DO @(
    Set /a size= %%~z_ / 1048576 & Echo. Mb    %computerName% _ %%~nxt_
)>>D:\out.txt
```

Comment: Гм... А что он должен делать? Мало того что файл ни разу не текстовый - так он же ещё и открыт сервисом эксклюзивно... да и не факт что у Вас есть права шариться в его каталоге.

Comment: он должен сохранить в файл out.txt вес файла Windows.edb

Comment: уж лучше forfiles: **forfiles /m Windows.edb /c "cmd /c echo @fsize"**